# "Show anyway" option to display hidden questions (due to ignored tags)

Tags: feature-request

I have a bunch of ignored tagged and in some rare cases, I don't want to have questions hidden anymore.

I may have missed it, but I don't think there is a simple way to temporarily deactivate these filters to show hidden questions anyway (appart from modifying my settings by removing ignored tags, which I prefer not to).

Would it be possible to add a `"Show anyway"` option to the hidden questions message:

[image]

Comment: Log out...problem solved!

Comment: There's a kind of middle ground where you can set that ignored tags should be "greyed out" rather than completely hidden - not sure if that's of use to you for now...

Comment: Very right, both solutions do the trick. Although it would be nice to have a one click solution.